# Server Response is: Bad Request: 400

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {

        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpsURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
           // dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }else{
            try{
                String sno = String.valueOf(439);
                String topic_id = String.valueOf(172);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);


                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();



                JSONObject jsonObjectPost1 = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjectPost1.put("sno", sno);
                jsonObjectPost1.put("topic_id", topic_id);
                jsonObjectPost1.put("attach_files", selectedFilePath);

                jsonArray.put(jsonObjectPost1);
                jsonObject.put("data", jsonArray);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               /* dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd); */
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(connection.toString());

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0){
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
              //  dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(connection.toString());

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

    }
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "m_insert_status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "message_text": "cHpqFzRfNs4xh7JrTq2phX9UeTKtCMO+gj3KKnRcc038Ja6tUetb/JD6zCDw6+X5dLP5iAZJUiL2LCPGcCDB0Q==",
            "message_link": 0,
            "userid": "165",
            "topic_id": "172",
            "reply_user_id": "0",
            "reply_message_id": "0"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Topic Insert Successfully"
}
```

Comment: But you are getting successful response, saying based on JSON that you received!

Comment: this is json formet not message

Comment: i want to put all object inside data array, using volley working fine but this way not working